# HTML & JS questionnaire not working to hide question just answered and show next

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write some HTML but Google showed I basically **need** Javascript to do what I am trying to do. I am trying to present the user a question, and some buttons for them to click that represent the answer. when a answer button is clicked the questions and buttons need to disappear and a new question and answer buttons need to appear, but the new question will be dependant on the prior questions answer and every question would have unique answer buttons.

There is some simple code that would hide things, but to use it as it was presented in the various places I found them would result in a mile of the same code being repeated at length so I tried to barrow knowledge I have learned elsewhere and what I could infer to make this a dynamic write it once use it many times bit of code.... but I would not be here asking for help if it worked and I am not sure why it doesn't.

```js
var hide;
var show;

function myFunction(current, next) {
  hide = current;
  show = next;
  var x = document.getElementById(hide);
  var y = document.getElementById(show);
  x.style.display = "none";
  y.style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<div id="myDIV">
  <button onclick="myFunction(myDIV, subDIV1)">Click Me 1</button>
  <button onclick="myFunction(myDIV, subDIV2)">Click Me 2</button>
  <button onclick="myFunction(myDIV, subDIV3)">Click Me 3</button> This is my DIV element.
</div>

<div id="subDIV1" style="display: none;">
  <button onclick="myFunction2(subDIV1, somethingElse1)">Now Me 1</button>
  <button onclick="myFunction2(subDIV1, somethingElse2)">Now Me 2</button>
  <button onclick="myFunction2(subDIV1, somethingElse3)">Now Me 3</button>
</div>

<div id="subDIV2" style="display: none;">
  <button onclick="myFunction2(subDIV2, somethingElse4)">Now Me 1</button>
  <button onclick="myFunction2(subDIV2, somethingElse5)">Now Me 2</button>
  <button onclick="myFunction2(subDIV2, somethingElse6)">Now Me 3</button>
</div>

<div id="subDIV3" style="display: none;">
  <button onclick="myFunction2(subDIV3, somethingElse7)">Now Me 1</button>
  <button onclick="myFunction2(subDIV3, somethingElse8)">Now Me 2</button>
  <button onclick="myFunction2(subDIV3, somethingElse9)">Now Me 3</button>
</div>
```

I was expecting that when I clicked a option in the first set of buttons the would hide and become one of the other sets of buttons depending on which was clicked. Instead nothing happened at all

Comment: Check your developer console. Javascript errors will appear there.

Comment: What are `myDIV`, `subDIV1`, etc? Did you mean to pass in strings to `myFunction`?

Comment: @DaveNewton those are the ID names of the html DIV's to be shown or hidden and are to be passed into the function for the function to set the value that show's or hides them

Comment: But they are variables that have not been set. If you want to use them as IDs, they should be strings wrapped in quotation marks.

Comment: @mykaf which is exactly what was wrong with the code and why it didn't work and what I came here to find because I was not seeing. Alan Ma said effectively the same thing below and when I tried it it worked hence I marked it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this `onclick="myFunction('myDIV', 'subDIV1')"` instead of `onclick="myFunction(myDIV, subDIV1)"`.

Comment: Thank you so very much that was perfect!

It shocks and sort of annoys me(in a good way) that for not looking at html in 3 years Javascript in like 9 years then googling today along with some limited knowledge of C++ from a class I am taking presently that I was able to bash togeather something that was only wrong by something so simple.

Though without you I would never have found it!

Comment: You're welcome. I am so glad my small assistance got you helped.